# Trouble changing variable in loop process

Tags: c, variables, loops

So the assignment is to ask for a variable in a certain range the print the individual digits of the numbers with three spaces in between the digit. For example 1234 should print

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
2 3 4
3 4 
4
```

I'm pretty sure I have most of the assignment done I am just having trouble changing the variable number in my loop. The number sorts itself into the right if statement but then when it loops instead of the number going down a digit (i.e. 2343 to 343) all it does is print the same number 5 times. I have researched in my book and looked online but i'm not seeing it. It's probably something simple just not sure what. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void loopingDigitprinter(int digit);
int division(int* digit);

int main() 
{
    int digitPrint;



    printf("Please enter a number between 0 and 32,767: ");
    scanf("%d", &digitPrint);
    loopingDigitprinter (digitPrint);

    return 0;
}

void loopingDigitprinter(int digit)
{
    int loopLine= 0;
   int thousand;
   int hundred;
   int original;
   original = digit;



    while(loopLine < 4)
    {
        if (digit > 10000 && digit <= 32767)
            {
                thousand = digit/ 1000;
                hundred = digit % 1000;
                printf("%02d%03d\n",thousand, hundred);
                digit %= 10000;


            }
        else if (digit < 10000 && digit > 1000)
            {

              if (original > 10000)
                    {   thousand = digit/ 1000;
                        hundred = digit % 1000;
                        digit %= 1000;
                        printf("%01d%03d\n",thousand, hundred);
                    }
            else
                    {
                        thousand = digit/ 1000;
                        hundred = digit % 1000;
                        printf("%02d%03d\n",thousand, hundred);
                        digit %= 1000;
                    }

            }
         else if (digit < 1000 && digit > 100)
            {
                if (original > 10000)
                    {
                         hundred = digit % 1000;
                         printf("%d\n",  hundred);
                         digit %= 100;
                    }  
                 else if (original < 10000 && original > 1000)
                    {
                        thousand = original / 1000;
                        hundred = digit % 1000;
                        printf("%d%d\n",thousand,digit);
                        printf("%d\n", digit);
                        digit %= 100;
                        digit %= 100;

                    }
                else
                    {
                         thousand = digit/ 1000;
                        hundred = digit % 1000;
                         printf("%02d%03d\n",thousand, hundred);
                        digit %= 1000;
                         thousand = original / 1000;
                         hundred = digit % 1000;
                         printf("%d%d\n",thousand,digit);
                         printf("%d\n", digit);
                         digit %= 100;
                         printf("%d\n", digit);
                         digit %= 10;
                         printf("%d\n", digit);
                     }

             }
         else if (digit < 100 && digit > 10)
            {
                if (original > 10000)
                     {   hundred = digit % 1000;
                         printf("%d\n", hundred);
                         digit %= 10;
                         printf("%d\n", digit);
                     }
                 else if (original < 10000 && original > 1000)
                     {
                         thousand = original / 1000;
                         hundred = digit % 1000;
                         printf("%d\n",hundred);
                         digit %= 10;
                        printf("%d\n", digit);
                    }
                 else if (original < 1000 && original > 10)
                    {
                        thousand = digit/ 1000;
                        hundred = digit % 1000;
                        printf("%02d%03d\n",thousand, hundred);
                        digit %= 1000;
                        thousand = original / 1000;
                        hundred = digit % 1000;
                        printf("%d%03d\n",thousand,digit);
                        printf("%03d\n", digit);
                        digit %= 100;
                        printf("%d\n", digit);
                        digit %= 10;
                        printf("%d\n", digit);

                    }
                else
                   printf("1");
               }

        else if(original > 0 && original < 10)

            {
                 printf("0000%d\n", original);
                 printf("000%d\n", original);
                 printf("00%d\n", original);
                 printf("0%d\n", original);
                 printf("%d\n", original);
                break;
            }



         loopLine++;
        }

        return;
 }
```

Comment: This is the updated code for anyone who runs into a similar problem. Works well just havent implemented the spaces yet. If there is a simpler solution I would like to know. Im trying to get a better grasp on implementing loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what you are doing there as i did not read the code.

But do refer to my sample code. It pretty much does the needful

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

int n,k,i=0;

printf("Enter a number please\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

while(i<=n){

    for(k=i;k<=n;k++){

        printf("%d ",k);

    }

    printf("\n");   
    i++;
}

return 0;
}


Output
------
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
2 3 4
3 4 
4
```

Answer (score 0):

The loopLine++ is called each loop so you eventually exit, but double check your last equality checks. Digit can't be greater than 10 AND less than 0.

You may need to call division(digit) in your last `else if` to make it change.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the equality check didnt even notice it. Calling division(digit) in the else if didn't change the variable so you whatever you type you get it printed 5 times

Comment: Figured it out. I wasn't passing the variable back up to the called function essentially rendering division null.